# How to send FormData with multiple files in chunks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to send formData with multiple files to the server. Is it possible to send it in chunks and include "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"? Code that works is simple however it's sending the payload with Content-Length and not chunked.

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('textSample', textSample)
formData.append('file1', somefile)
formData.append('file2', somefile2)

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('POST', "/upload")
xhr.send(formData)
```

Is it even possible? Are there any libraries that support this?

Comment: What is your use case? It's not an option for you to simply do one request per file in sequence instead?

Comment: Not without reworking the service

Answer (score 0):

You are not all allowed to set `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` because it is a [Response Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) which means that you can not set it inside a browser. However some of [this](https://gist.github.com/shiawuen/1534477) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235709/using-xhr-object-for-html5-chunked-upload-in-a-loop) might help you in achieving the goal.

Comment: Please add comments if I am wrong, not only an upvote